# Is there a way I could get auto string from HTML depending on time

Tags: html, sql, datetime

I'm looking for a solution similar to SQL in html
For example in SQL

```
Case when date between 00:00:00 and 12:00:00 then "morning"
else "afternoon"
end as Morning/afternoon
```

Comment: Where do you want to perform this calculation? Do you want to use JavaScript? Please [edit] the question to make it clearer what you are asking.

Comment: I wanted to use Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in Java script tag:

```
    var myDate = new Date();
    var hrs = myDate.getHours();
    var greet;

    if (hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 11.59)
        greet = 'Good Morning';
    else if (hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 17)
        greet = 'Good Afternoon';
    else if (hrs >= 17 && hrs <= 24)
        greet = 'Good Evening';

    document.getElementById('TIME').innerHTML = greet;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal using javascript code with HTML like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">hello</p>

<script>
if (new Date().getHours() < 12) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Morning";
}
else if (new Date().getHours() >= 12) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Afternoon";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```